# RSA with Javascript and Python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, rsa

I have to encrypt something in Javascript and decrypt in Python using RSA. I have decided to use pidCrypt https://www.pidder.com/pidcrypt/?page=demo_rsa-encryption for the former and Pycrypto library for the latter. But when I try to decrypt using the pyCrypto library (using PKCS v1.5 module), I get this error "Ciphertext with incorrect length." What could be causing this and is there a way to fix this? Here is my code:

**Encryption JS:**

```
var crypted = encrypt("Hello");  
var base64Crypted = pidCryptUtil.encodeBase64(crypted);
```

I write the encrypted data to a file encr.txt and then read and decrypt in python as follows:

**Decryption Python:**

```
mk = open('mykey.pem','r')  
myKey = RSA.importKey(mk.read())   
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(myKey)  
ef = open('encr.txt','r')  
encrData = base64.b64decode(ef.read())  
decr = cipher.decrypt(encrData, sentinel)
```

Here is my key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It means your padding scheme is not padding out data correctly. Are you using the same padding scheme on both sides?

Comment: Can you show the text as well as the keys? Can you show the code?

Comment: Hi Chris, The comments in the pidder library says they use PKCS#1 encryption-style padding (type 2) and the PyCrypto comments say they use PKCS#1 v1.5 (specifically RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5-DECRYPT function defined in section 7.2.2 of RFC3447). I was under the assumption that they were both the same. Maybe I am wrong?